# How to change countdown to hour/minutes/seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter so im just trying to learn as much as possible. I want to try and make an alarm clock but now im stuck on the time format. This is the current code:

```
from tkinter import *

teer = Tk()
field = Canvas(teer, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, height='190', width='400', bg='#111111')
field.pack()

def start_countdown(count):
    coin = 0.5
    teer.resizable(False,False)
    counter = Label(teer, fg = "#287aff", bg='#232323', font = ("Lato", 35, "bold"), width='15')
    counter.place(x=50, y=50)
    counter["text"] = count
    if count > 0:
       teer.after(1000, start_countdown, count -1)
    if count < 500:
       coin = 0.6
    if count < 300:
       coin = 0.7

start_countdown(500)
teer.mainloop()
```

now what i've been trying to do is chop the 500 (seconds) up into minutes / seconds. Or ultimately change it to hours / minutes / seconds if i may choose to insert an int larger than 3600 into the function. I just want the time hardcoded so i thought it wouldn't be such a problem.

*What i tried:*

-Experimented with different alarms / countdowns that people made (sadly there aren't many out there that count down instead of up and are also in hours/minutes/seconds.

-Experimented with the format (for example) %H:%M:%S

I Just don't seem to get it.
Would appreciate any help or advice about making a GUI-program that counts down.

Comment: So you want to have `start_countdown(1:30:25)` instead of `start_countdown(500)`?

Comment: @Alderven       So what i want to achieve is; lets say i insert 3600 into the function. that is 1 hour which should start the timer at 1:00:00

Comment: What will happen if you pass `3600` in your function now?

Comment: @Alderven      It starts counting down from 3600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `divmod` to calculate the remaining time.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

a = tk.Label(root,text="")
a.pack()

def set_idle_timer(t):
    hours, remainder = divmod(t, 3600)
    mins, secs = divmod(remainder, 60)
    timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, mins, secs)
    a.config(text=timeformat)
    t -=1
    root.after(1000,lambda: set_idle_timer(t))

set_idle_timer(3605)

root.mainloop()
```