# `text.config` crashes because of an overload of events

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I asked a question like this here: 
[How to adjust Label in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310299/how-to-adjust-label-in-tkinter)

But the events load up and eventually python can't handle the events, and it crashes.

How to make this not happen?? Maybe because it's in a loop, so they overload?
I can't figure out how to make it not crash.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from time import *
print("""This is an app that basically you time the amount of time someone takes to fall from a cliff, then we will
use an equation to tell you how high the cliff is.
This is a recreation of the app Mark Rober created, by The way""")
window = Tk()
window.title("falling app")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg = "sky blue")
"""We will use time import for this"""
mins = 0
seconds = 0
secs = Label(window, text = seconds, font = ("verdana", 60))
secs.place(relx = 0.48, rely = 0.35, anchor = "nw")
def start():
    mins = 0
    seconds = 0
    while seconds != 60:
        sleep(1.00)
        seconds+= 1
        secs.configure(text = seconds)
    if seconds == 60:
        mins = mins+1
        seconds = 0
```

This line: `secs.configure(text = seconds)` is the culprit. Im sure of it.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!

Edit: This is what it looks like, it blanks out, and becomes unresponsive.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share [mcve] to reproduce the issue? How do you use your function `start`?

Comment: You can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141009/how-to-change-countdown-to-hour-minutes-seconds) - just replace `t-=1` to `t+=1`.

Comment: When it crashes, what does it do? Do you get an error? Is this really your actual code? I don't see why it would cause the program to crash _per se_, but it definitely will freeze for a full sixty seconds.

Comment: @bryan oakley it crashes and says windows is figuring out what went wrong then it closes

Comment: You script should be finished very quickly without showing anything because it does not run either `start()` or `mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 What I mean is that it runs perfectly for a second, then it crashes and freezes. Also, for me `mainloop()` isn't needed I work perfectly without it. All `mainloop()` does is make your program run forever and to quit it you have to kill it.

Comment: @BryanOakley at first it freezes, then windows says there's a problem, and I have to close it eventually.

Comment: @Programmer What I mean is that your code does not call either your function `start()` or tkinter `mainloop()`, so it should terminates very quickly.  For your case, you should at least call `start()` at the end of the script.  If you put `secs.update()` after `secs.configure(...)`, you should get your window show up and counting for 60 seconds.

Comment: No @BryanOakley I call start in the shell window

Comment: Here is a picture of what happens: It becomes unresponsive: Ill edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the program hangs is because you've created an endless loop which prevents tkinter from ever being able to process events. Tkinter is single threaded, and can only work when it is able to process a steady flow of events. You've prevented that with this infinite loop:

```
while seconds != 60:
    sleep(1.00)
    seconds+= 1
    secs.configure(text = seconds)
```

A quick fix is to call `update` in that loop. Your program will still freeze for one second, and then become active for just a few milliseconds before freezing again. That's a very inefficient way to write a tkinter program.

The better way would be use use the `after` method to continually schedule your function to run once every second. There are probably dozens of not hundreds of examples of that technique on this site. In a nutshell it looks something like this:

```
def update_clock()
    global mins, seconds
    seconds += 1
    if seconds > 60:
        seconds = 0
        mins += 1
    secs.configure(text = seconds)

    window.after(1000, update_clock)
```

You then call this function once in your `start` method, and it will continue to run every second until the program quits:

```
def start():
    global mins, seconds
    mins = 0
    seconds = 0
    update_clock()
```